# Laravel - user login

Tags: laravel, logging

I use Laravel 5.4 and need to login user in my system. I have next login.blade.php
where i have email and password field. In my controller I have next

```
protected function log() {

 $email=Input::get('email');  
 $pass=Input::get('password');     

  $user = DB::select("SELECT * FROM users where email = '".$email."' and password = '".$pass."'");

  foreach($user as $users){
     if(Input::get('email') == $users->email){
         return redirect('/');
  }else{
        return view('site.warning');

     }
   }  

   }
```

How can I return logged user in my  redirect('/') and show them in my site.
Any idea?

Comment: what do you mean "How can I return loget"

Comment: Sorry, i mean logged

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`attempt()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users) method:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
```

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users):

> The attempt method accepts an array of key / value pairs as its first argument. The values in the array will be used to find the user in your database table. So, in the example above, the user will be retrieved by the value of the email column. If the user is found, the hashed password stored in the database will be compared with the password value passed to the method via the array.

This method will work for you if you're using `bcrypt()` or `Hash::make()` to [generate password hash](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/hashing).

Comment: How does that work ? I understand you select the user based on requested email. But how can you attempt him via password? When I bcrypt some string to hash, I get different hash each time. Bcrypt is one way operation, isn't it?

Comment: @Epsilon47 yes it works. Laravel uses this method internally to check email/password and authenticate users.

Comment: I have not known about that. But its cool stuff I will take a look about how it works

Comment: @Epsilon47 you might want to read about [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Laravel uses it internally `password_verify($value, $hashedValue)`

Comment: I am just wondering hows that possible that it is safe. If that algorithm can compare hashed password and unhashed password and state that they equal there somehow must be the way to decrypt it. But I guess this question is discussed somewhere(:

Comment: @Epsilon47 it is safe. You store a copy of your hashed password. You hash the plaintext password and compare the 2. if they are equal the original passwords are (most likely) the same. You will however not be able to retrieve the original password from the hash.

Answer (score 1):

**Please do not create your own login system!**
Now that's out of the way the explanation.
There is (almost) no good reason to create your own login system, as your code already showed. Your current code is very VERY insecure due to storing passwords in plain text. Please read up on resent security advice.

The even better option is using Laravels build-in auth.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication

If you do try to use this build-in authentication methods you will be able to get the current authenticated user by using `Auth::user()` this can be used in your blade files as well as in your controllers.

Comment: I have two login form in my site, because i need to create custom form...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (maybe you can) but you certainly should't store user's password unhashed. Laravel has build artisan command: `php artisan make:auth`. You may use it, and retrieve him in the `show` method for example (thro the URL, passing id). Or just retrieve him via `Auth::user()`. Planty of choices.

Comment: It is simple operation. When you are using Laravel, you should be using also the terminal so you are able to type artisan commands. There you will type php artisan so you see a list of options you have. So you will find there php artisan make:auth. After submitting it your auth system is done. You can pass then authenticated user like so.
`$user = Auth::user();
 return View::make('auth.index', compact('user'));`